# Where to find Google Play Services v4.2.34?

Tags: google-play-services, chromecast

AllCast with Chromecast support needs Google Play Services v4.2.34. I used Google Search but I not found it.

Comment: Reading the announcements would have shown you that the roll out had started but will take a few days to reach all the devices and then the Play services update will be released into the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the source code for GPS, then Ali's answer is the best one. If you just want the binary libraries that are rolling out now, then here's the download link to the APK: http://www.mediafire.com/download/5cozzv82il95ppr/com.google.android.gms-4.2.39+%28997510-038%29.apk

The APK is signed by Google and will update the current version you have.